# Character is letter at java

Tags: java

```
public boolean isAnagram(ArrayList<Character> arr1, ArrayList<Character> arr2) {
    if( arr1 == null || arr2 == null || arr1.isEmpty() || arr2.isEmpty()){
        return false;// TODO
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < arr1.size(); i++){
        if(arr1.get(i) == Character.isLetter()){
            Character.toLowerCase(arr1.get(i));
             return true;
        }
```

Thats a Part of my Code, and i do not understand what I should write into Character.isLetter(DONT KNOW)) --> ps. also do not know, wheater that Code works
I want that he Returns true, when i is a Letter.

Comment: I don't know either, since you didn't say what was supposed to happen.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider As name of the function suggests, It should check for anagrams!

Comment: i want to check the Elements of a given Array, and also want that the Programm Returns true, when the Character is a letter

Comment: What do you want finally? Check for anagrams or Check for letter?

Comment: @SanketMakani that right, thanks

Comment: Check whater the two Arrays are anagrams

Comment: Yes i typed that in, but he gave me a compilation failour.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code for  isAnagram method

```
public boolean isAnagram(ArrayList<Character> arr1, ArrayList<Character> arr2) {
    if( arr1 == null || arr2 == null || arr1.isEmpty() || arr2.isEmpty())
        return false;// TODO

    if(arr1.size() != arr2.size()) return false;

    for(int i = 0; i < arr1.size(); i++){
        if(arr1.get(i) != arr2.get(arr2.size() - i))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank u, but i think, in the Array are also integers and i have to remove them first before checking if they are an anagram.